# Ошибка: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)

Tags: python, websocket

ошибок не было но вдруг когда я подключился к другому вайфай вот такая ошибка
Ошибка: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)

```
import websocket
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

def add_item(rates_element, from_currency, to_currency, value):
    # Проверяем наличие элемента 'rates'
    if rates_element is None:
        rates_element = ET.Element('rates')

    # Проверяем, существует ли элемент 'item' для указанной валютной пары
    item_element = None
    for item in rates_element.findall('item'):
        if item.find('from').text == from_currency and item.find('to').text == to_currency:
            item_element = item
            break

    # Если элемент не существует, создаем новый
    if item_element is None:
        item_element = ET.SubElement(rates_element, 'item')
        ET.SubElement(item_element, 'from').text = from_currency
        ET.SubElement(item_element, 'to').text = to_currency
        ET.SubElement(item_element, 'in').text = '1'
        ET.SubElement(item_element, 'amount').text = '31.90343295'
        ET.SubElement(item_element, 'minamount').text = '100'
        ET.SubElement(item_element, 'maxamount').text = '1000000'
        ET.SubElement(item_element, 'fromfee').text = '2.15%'
        ET.SubElement(item_element, 'city').text = 'ALIC'

    # Очищаем элемент 'item' и обновляем значение 'out'
    item_element.clear()
    ET.SubElement(item_element, 'from').text = from_currency
    ET.SubElement(item_element, 'to').text = to_currency
    ET.SubElement(item_element, 'in').text = '1'
    ET.SubElement(item_element, 'out').text = str(value)
    ET.SubElement(item_element, 'amount').text = '31.90343295'
    ET.SubElement(item_element, 'minamount').text = '100'
    ET.SubElement(item_element, 'maxamount').text = '1000000'
    ET.SubElement(item_element, 'fromfee').text = '2.15%'
    ET.SubElement(item_element, 'city').text = 'ALIC'

def on_message(ws, message):
    data = json.loads(message)

    if data[3] == "USDT/EUR":
        value_usdt_eur = round(float(data[1]["a"][0]), 6)
        value_eur_usdt = round(1.0 / float(data[1]["a"][0]), 6)


        add_item(rates_element, 'USDTTRC20', 'CASHEUR', value_usdt_eur)
        add_item(rates_element, 'CASHEUR', 'USDTTRC20', value_eur_usdt)

        add_item(rates_element, 'CASHEUR', 'CASHUSD', value_eur_usdt)
        add_item(rates_element, 'CASHUSD', 'CASHEUR', value_usdt_eur)


    if data[3] == "USDT/USD":
        value_usdt_usd = round(float(data[1]["a"][0]), 6)
        value_usd_usdt = round(1.0 / float(data[1]["a"][0]), 6)

        add_item(rates_element, 'USDTTRC20', 'CASHUSD', value_usdt_usd)
        add_item(rates_element, 'CASHUSD', 'USDTTRC20', value_usd_usdt)

    # Сохраняем все данные о валютных парам в файл после обработки каждого сообщения
    save_to_xml()

def save_to_xml():
    xml_str = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(rates_element)).toprettyxml(indent="    ")

    # Записываем XML в файл 'output.xml'
    with open('server/courses.xml', 'w') as f:
        f.write(xml_str)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(f"Ошибка: {error}")

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("WebSocket соединение закрыто")

def on_open(ws):
    payload = {
        "event": "subscribe",
        "pair": ["USDT/USD", "USDT/EUR", "EUR/ZGBP"],
        "subscription": {
            "name": "ticker"
        }
    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(payload))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.kraken.com/", on_message=on_message, on_error=on_error, on_close=on_close)

    # Создаем элемент 'rates' для XML
    rates_element = ET.Element('rates')

    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```